# EC2 Multiple Simultaneous Network Requests With Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, network-programming

Can Amazon's EC2 instances make multiple, simultaneous network requests?

I'm pinging a few different api's with the same query. I'm wondering if I break my api request loop into subprocesses (using python's subprocess) if I'm just creating a network que or am I actually splitting my bandwidth for each call?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your application creates it's own socket you should be splitting bandwidth.

You can check if it's true with `sudo netstat -apeen` command.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  It's hard for me to decipher what I'm looking for in sudo netstat -apeen.  Any suggestions or links on how to read that?